# Why address of the same members of std::vector is different in comparison function of std::sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl, lambda

I'm wondering why this code print the same members address  differently :

```
template <typename FI>
void sorta(FI begin, FI end){
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<FI>::value_type;
    std::sort(begin, end, [](const T& lhs,const T& rhs){
         std::cout << lhs<<"**"<<&lhs  << '\n';
         return std::rand()%2;
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1,5,3,4,7};
    sorta(a.begin(),a.end());
}
```

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d732a786b464a26)

possible outputs :

```
5**0x25e5014
3**0x25e5018
3**0x7fff93d5d3e0
...
```

As you can see address of variable 3 is different in every function call !

It seems weird I tried a simple function which is do something simillar to  std::sort :

```
using Iterator=std::vector<int>::iterator;
template<class Func>
void foo(Iterator begin,Iterator end,Func f)
{
    for(Iterator it=begin; it != end-1;++it)
    {
         auto f2=[&begin,&f](int& lhs,int& rhs){
            std::cout<<&(*begin)<<"\n"<<&lhs<<"  "<<&rhs;
            f(lhs,rhs);
        };

         f2(*it,*(it+1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1,5,3,4,7};

    foo(a.begin(),a.end(),[](int& lhs,int& rhs){
        std::cout<<"\n"<<&lhs<<"  "<<&rhs<<"\n\n\n";
    });
}
```

[live](https://ideone.com/cRXzZL)

possible outputs:

```
0x837a008
0x837a008  0x837a00c
0x837a008  0x837a00c

0x837a008
0x837a00c  0x837a010
0x837a00c  0x837a010

...
```

Surprise !

Addresses are same in this case , So I expect the std::sort do the same thing !!

What is wrong with the first code ? Is std::sort copying variables multiple times?!

**use case :**

I'm trying to write a sort function which return source indices too but because of the problem that I explained It doesn't work

```
template <typename FI ,class L >
std::vector<int> sorta(FI begin, FI end, L comp_proc){
    size_t size = std::distance(begin, end);
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<FI>::value_type;

    std::vector <int> indexs(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indexs.size(); i++)
        indexs[i] = i;

    std::sort(begin, end, [&comp_proc,&begin,&indexs](const T& l_item,const T& r_item){

        size_t l_dis = std::distance(&(*begin),const_cast<T*>(&l_item));//not working correctly
        size_t r_dis = std::distance(&(*begin),const_cast<T*>(&r_item));//not working correctly
        std::cout << l_item<<"**"<<&l_item <<"**"<<l_dis << "**" << r_dis << std::endl;

        bool res = comp_proc(l_item, r_item);
        if (const_cast<T*>(&l_item) > &(*begin) && const_cast<T*>(&r_item) > &(*begin)){
            if (res){
                std::swap(indexs[l_dis], indexs[r_dis]);//not working
            }
        }

        return res;
    });
    return indexs;

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{1,5,3,4,7};
    std::vector<int> indexes=sorta(a.begin(),a.end(),[](const int& a,const int& b){return a<b;});

    std::cout<<"\n";
    for(auto i:indexes)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<"\n";
    }
}
```

[live](https://ideone.com/eq0wF7)

Other solutions for writing such function also appreciated (without making and sorting a std::pair)

Comment: `sort` is allowed to use local variables and compare them to elements of sorted range. It is not guaranteed that all pointers will point to elements of array.

Comment: Your asking why the "same" entries have different addresses in a *sort* routine? The entries are *moved* during the sort including occupying temporaries (and in this case, utterly unpredictably because you're comparator is violating the strict weak order required by `std::sort`). " So I expect the std::sort do the same thing." - Had you written it, it probably would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) uses a sort with `O(n*log(n))` complexity. It can be for example (an optimized version of) [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). It selects a pivot, moves the smaller elements before the pivot, the bigger elements after the pivot and repeats it recursively on the first and second half.

That also mean that `std::sort` is allowed to (and to be fast it needs to) move the elements of the `vector` multiple times during the sort. The comparison function will see them at their current location.

The odd out-of-vector addresses show that `std::sort` moves elements during sorting to the stack as well. To be specific: (g++ 4.8.2) for example `__unguarded_linear_insert` in `bits/std_algo.h` moves its argument to the stack.

---

The original positions of the elements are lost during the sort. You have to use `std::pair` or some other method to store the original positions if you want to use them.

---

From Angew's answer: Also an important note that your comparator is not consistent. This is undefined behaviour and can give [segfaults](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb4fc5b0fad09e8e) with different input.

Comment: This does not explain why he sees addresses that are clearly _outside_ the vector.

Comment: @ComicSansMS my guess is that `std::sort` saves the pivot into a local variable.

Comment: @Csq: To be honest, I am surprised it does, as this may imply an expensive copy; but the address is pretty clear indeed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. found it in the code :) (updated the answer). `sort` moves the elements several times anyway.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you have undefined behaviour because the predicate you're passing to `std::sort` is not internally consistent - it's possible it will report `a < b` and `b < a` at the same time.

Even without that, the purpose of `std::sort` is to *sort* the range - exchange elements within it so that they're in the correct order (according to the predicate). So of course the elements will move around the range.

Answer (score 3):

It prints out different adresses, because some of the elements are stored in temporary variables, on the stack, while others being moved.

```
5**0x25e5014    // This is in the original array
3**0x25e5018    // This too
3**0x7fff93d5d3e0   // This is on the stack
```

The "smaller" memory addresses usually correspond to values in the file's images (function addresses, global variables, etc.) while the highers are usually heap or stack allocated addresses. 0x7fff******** is usually on the stack in 64 bit programs, but it's just from my personal experience in debugging, and not set in stone.